# Moose and constraint class variables

Tags: perl, moose

I have the following propertiy on Moose class

```
package myPackage;
 use Moose;

has Number => (
  is  => 'rw',
  isa => Num,

 );
```

is there an option with Moose to constraint this type to float number from 0 to 100 and if someone try to insert number not on the range of 0-100 then the value will be undef if yes how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do as requested...

```
{
  package MyPackage;
  use Moose;
  use Types::Standard qw( Maybe Num );
  use Types::Numbers qw( NumRange );

  has n => (
    is     => 'rw',
    isa    => (Maybe[ NumRange[0,100] ])->plus_coercions(Num, sub { undef }),
    coerce => 1,
  );
}

print MyPackage->new( n =>  99 )->dump;
print MyPackage->new( n => 100 )->dump;
print MyPackage->new( n => 101 )->dump;
```

**Update:** a few explanations...

This is a type constraint for a number between 0 and 100:

```
NumRange[0,100]
```

Wrapping it with `Maybe[...]` allows `undef` to be accepted as a value:

```
Maybe[ NumRange[0,100] ]
```

Now we need to call a method on the type constraint object returned by that expression. The "obvious" `Maybe[...]->methodname` won't work because of the precedence of the `->` operator (it would try to call the method on the arrayref, and pass the result to `Maybe`). So we need to provide some parentheses to do the method call `(Maybe[...])->methodname`.

The method we'll be calling is `plus_coercions`, defined in [Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type%3a%3aTiny) (the underlying type constraint library used by both Types::Standard and Types::Numbers). This creates a new subtype of `Maybe[NumRange[0,100]]` but adding some coercions to it.

The coercion we add is:

```
Num, sub { undef }
```

... which means "if the value to be coerced is a number, run this sub and use its output". In the sub we don't need to check if the value being coerced is outside the 0..100 range because coercions will only be triggered if the value fails the `Maybe[NumRange[0,100]]` type constraint.

In fact, we could also express it like this:

```
(Maybe[ NumRange[0,100] ])->plus_coercions(Num, 'undef')
```

... using a string of Perl code instead of a sub. This is perhaps slightly less clear, but may run ever so slightly faster because it allows Type::Tiny to play tricks with inlining code. (By which I basically mean concatenating various strings of Perl code and `eval`ing them, so that it can end up with a single sub that does the entire check/coercion rather than needing to call different subs to do the checks and the coercions.)

In this case it's unlikely to make any perceivable difference to performance, but if you had a large arrayref of such numbers you wanted to coerce, you might notice.

```
ArrayRef[ (Maybe[NumRange[0,100]])->plus_coercions(Num, 'undef') ]
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes. Refer to the TypeConstraints documentation and how to coerce a value.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Util::TypeConstraints](http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose%3a%3aUtil%3a%3aTypeConstraints)

Comment: could you provide an example how if the value is not between 0 and 100 to set it to undef ? thanks

Comment: This answer could use some additional details (like an example of *how* to do what the OP is asking). Currently it is basically just a link, which is [discouraged for a number of reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).